# Shortcut to sine series using regular expansion?

Tags: fourier-series

If we're given the Fourier series of $e^x$ on the interval $(0,2\pi)$, I'm wondering if there's a nicer way to extract the sine series of $e^x$ on the same interval other than getting the coefficients by the integral $\int e^x sin(nx) dx$. For the record

$e^x = ((e^{2\pi}-1)/2\pi)\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{cos(nx)+i sin(nx)}{1-in}$ on $(0,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why you might want another approach, seeing that the relevant integral is quite straightforward. But just for the record, here is 
an approach using a differential equation and assuming knowledge of the 
complex Fourier series of $x$ on the interval $[0,2\pi]$, which is 
$$  \pi + \sum_{\stackrel{n=-\infty}{n\not=0}}^\infty \frac{ie^{inx}}{n}\ .  $$

Let's look at the function 
$$ f(x) = e^x - \frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{2\pi} x\ . $$
This is smooth on $(0,2\pi)$ and satisfies $f(0) = f(2\pi) (= 1)$ so we can 
differentiate its Fourier series term-by-term. And it satisfies the differential equation 
$$f' -f  =  \frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{2\pi} (x-1)\ .   $$
Suppose now the Fourier series of $f$ is 
$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{inx}\ .  $$
Substituting into the differential equation we have 
$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (in-1) c_n e^{inx} 
    =   \frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{2\pi} \left(  \pi - 1 +  
              \sum_{\stackrel{n=-\infty}{n\not=0}}^\infty \frac{ie^{inx}}{n}  \right)   $$
so 
$$ c_0 = \frac{(e^{2\pi}-1)(1-\pi)}{2\pi} \ , \quad 
   c_n = \frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{2\pi}\frac{i}{n(in-1)} \quad n\not=0 
$$
Finally we use  $e^x = f + \frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{2\pi} x $ to get the Fourier series of $e^x$. It is 
$$ \left(\frac{(e^{2\pi}-1)(1-\pi)}{2\pi} + 
\sum_{\stackrel{n=-\infty}{n\not=0}}^\infty 
 \frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{2\pi}\frac{i}{n(in-1)} e^{inx}\right)
 +  \frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{2\pi}\left(
\pi + \sum_{\stackrel{n=-\infty}{n\not=0}}^\infty \frac{ie^{inx}}{n}
\right) 
$$
which simplifies to 
$$ \frac{e^{2\pi}-1}{2\pi} 
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty 
    \frac{e^{inx}}{1-in}
$$